# handling css multiple div's

Tags: css, html

I need to arrange multiple div's like,

[image]

code:

```
<style>
#div1 {
    background: yellow;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:177px;
}
#div2 {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    width: 177px;
    clear: left;
}
#div3 {
    background: blue;
    margin-left:180px;
    position:relative;
}

#div4 {
    position: relative;
}
</style>

<div id="div1">
    <p><strong>DIV1:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis ante leo. Fusce at lacus risus. Fusce felis tortor, vehicula ut vulputate sit amet, ultricies sit amet risus.</p>
</div>
<div id="div4">
    <div id="div2">
        <p><strong>DIV2:</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis ante leo. Fusce at lacus risus. Fusce felis tortor, vehicula ut vulputate sit amet, ultricies sit amet risus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <p><strong>DIV3:</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis ante leo. Fusce at lacus risus. Fusce felis tortor, vehicula ut vulputate sit amet, ultricies sit amet risus. Donec venenatis, nulla et ultrices varius, ligula sapien pharetra dolor, eget vulputate justo felis ac leo. Morbi nec ullamcorper purus. Nulla mollis dignissim nisi in imperdiet. Phasellus convallis ante a felis tincidunt hendrerit. Praesent ipsum lorem, mollis sed dignissim non, consectetur non ipsum. Nam euismod, nisi ut ultricies aliquet, lorem erat pretium tortor, eget volutpat lectus tellus at magna. Curabitur a est ante, interdum faucibus ipsum. Mauris vitae tincidunt nisl. Praesent semper erat sit amet augue pharetra tristique. Morbi imperdiet, magna et malesuada interdum, massa ipsum venenatis est, sit amet egestas risus sem a purus.</p>
        <p>Duis in sagittis justo. Quisque sit amet felis in tortor pharetra bibendum. Mauris eget purus sit amet magna vulputate ultricies. Nam non dignissim nisl. Suspendisse pretium malesuada dolor, non lacinia tellus imperdiet ullamcorper. Sed commodo placerat lacus eu bibendum. In id elit sed velit iaculis pulvinar et id elit. Cras sagittis porttitor tristique. Vivamus sed sodales lectus. Nulla interdum, mi sit amet volutpat feugiat, nunc erat consectetur neque, rutrum rutrum lorem nisl pellentesque magna. Maecenas mollis consequat fringilla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam eu mi pellentesque turpis faucibus vestibulum quis in ligula. Donec mollis tempor velit, eget vestibulum ante elementum ac. In gravida, purus sed faucibus rhoncus, arcu augue pretium nibh, ut faucibus justo ante vitae metus. Nunc sit amet mauris urna.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help on this div3 to go top
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please specify the *versions* of IE and firefox you're testing with, (and if possible, whether the same thing happens in other versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked, Thanks NGLN, Your suggestion helped me a lot.

```
<style>
#div1 {
    background: yellow;
    float:left;
    width:177px;
}
#div2 {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 177px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
#div3 {
    background: blue;
    margin-left: 185px;
    position: relative;
}

#div4 {
    display: inline;
}


</style>

<div id="div1">
    <p><strong>DIV1:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis ante leo. Fusce at lacus risus. Fusce felis tortor, vehicula ut vulputate sit amet, ultricies sit amet risus.</p>
</div>

<div id="div4">
    <div id="div2">
        <p><strong>DIV2:</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis ante leo. Fusce at lacus risus. Fusce felis tortor, vehicula ut vulputate sit amet, ultricies sit amet risus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <p><strong>DIV3:</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis ante leo. Fusce at lacus risus. Fusce felis tortor, vehicula ut vulputate sit amet, ultricies sit amet risus. Donec venenatis, nulla et ultrices varius, ligula sapien pharetra dolor, eget vulputate justo felis ac leo. Morbi nec ullamcorper purus. Nulla mollis dignissim nisi in imperdiet. Phasellus convallis ante a felis tincidunt hendrerit. Praesent ipsum lorem, mollis sed dignissim non, consectetur non ipsum. Nam euismod, nisi ut ultricies aliquet, lorem erat pretium tortor, eget volutpat lectus tellus at magna. Curabitur a est ante, interdum faucibus ipsum. Mauris vitae tincidunt nisl. Praesent semper erat sit amet augue pharetra tristique. Morbi imperdiet, magna et malesuada interdum, massa ipsum venenatis est, sit amet egestas risus sem a purus.</p>
        <p>Duis in sagittis justo. Quisque sit amet felis in tortor pharetra bibendum. Mauris eget purus sit amet magna vulputate ultricies. Nam non dignissim nisl. Suspendisse pretium malesuada dolor, non lacinia tellus imperdiet ullamcorper. Sed commodo placerat lacus eu bibendum. In id elit sed velit iaculis pulvinar et id elit. Cras sagittis porttitor tristique. Vivamus sed sodales lectus. Nulla interdum, mi sit amet volutpat feugiat, nunc erat consectetur neque, rutrum rutrum lorem nisl pellentesque magna. Maecenas mollis consequat fringilla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam eu mi pellentesque turpis faucibus vestibulum quis in ligula. Donec mollis tempor velit, eget vestibulum ante elementum ac. In gravida, purus sed faucibus rhoncus, arcu augue pretium nibh, ut faucibus justo ante vitae metus. Nunc sit amet mauris urna.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the beginning of your question :

```
I need to arrange multiple div's like,

[  div1  ]   [  div3 ]
[  div2  ]   [   ""  ]
```

I simply ignored the code you supplied. I noticed you wanted a 2 columns system.

[Here's a jsfiddle of my suggestion](http://jsfiddle.net/TuGA6/).

Code :

```
.col {float:left; border:2px solid red;}
.row{width:100px;border:1px solid blue; margin:3px;}

<div class="col">
    <div class="row">row1</div>
    <div class="row">row2</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">row3</div>
    <div class="row">row4</div>
</div>
```

Would that work for you? If not, why?

Comment: Seems to make more sense to me

Comment: Hi, I am glad I got the reply finally but I think my view in boxes are pretty confused you. Please check My edit question with image. Please help me out on this.

Comment: for a purpose I am putting div2 and div3 in div4. Because I have some links in Div1 and when I click it, using jquery ajax call I will update the div4. A bit weird scenario but need it :(

Comment: @Max I don't see why it matters to your grid which div it's in, you can just change your JQuery selector to something else.  Kraz's answer should work, just remove the "row4" div, so something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TuGA6/5/

Comment: @Davy8: I understood the solution but my problem is, in the above given suggestion, remove the row2 in first div col and add instead of row3 change to row2 and still the output should look same as what fiddle looks now.  If my row2 is in first div col then its a straight forward solution but its not the scenario

Comment: @Max : I'm glad you found a way to do it like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/7dJZb/1/)**?

Tested on Win7 in IE8, IE9, Opera 11.50, FF4, FF5, Safari 5, Chrome 12.

Only IE7 fails. For that you need an extra conditional stylesheet like in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/7dJZb/2/)**:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    position: relative;
  }
  #div3 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

If you really want it cross browser compatible, without consitional stylesheet for IE7, then I suppose there is no way around partially absolute positioning. See **[this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/7dJZb/4/)**.

Comment: This fiddle example is good but please let me know if there is any possibility of working in IE8 without the condition. I will also try from my end. Thanks Buddy.

Comment: @Max It works in IE8 without the conditional style. `[if lt IE 8]` means `if < IE8`. If you really want it cross browser compatible without conditional stylesheet for IE7, look at my revision.

Comment: Hi NGLN, your suggestion helped me a lot. Thanks for that. I solved it and posted the answer